# Add Find Special Character at beginning and ADD to END of string with regex

Tags: regex

Have a string that starts with a # symbol and would like to add the same # symbol.

The string could contain any type of lower/upper, numbers, comas, periods, etc. Each string is a single separate line.

Here is what I have tried with no success:

```
Find:       (?=#)([\S\s]+)           # www.admitme.app
Find:       (?=#\B)([\S\s]+)         # Carlo Baxter
Find:       (?=#\B)([A-Za-z0-9]+)    # resumes in 15 minutes

Replace:    $1 #                     # resumes in 15 minutes #
```

Yes I'm a noob with regex...
Thanks in advance
Hank K

Comment: Your current regex replacement seems to be doing the job, so what is the problem/question here?

Comment: Only adds the # symbol to the last string and not the first two https://regex101.com/r/bxPwuy/1

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern is working in your demo:

```
(?=#\B)(.*)
```

This works in multiline mode, because then the `.*` will not match across newlines.  You were using `[\s\S]*`, which will match across newlines, even in multiline mode.  Here is the updated [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bxPwuy/2).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same replacement without lookarounds or capture groups using one of these patterns. The point is to match any character without newlines using `.*` (And not have a flag set to have the dot matches newlines)

```
#\B.*
# .*
```

In the replacement use the [matched text](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacematch.html) followed by a space and `#`

```
$0 #
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E33u6u/1).